# Getting the pixel coordinate of an image clicking with the mouse in Python

Tags: python, mouseclick-event

I was sure this would be a simple task but in two days of searches and implementations, I was not able to solve it.

The goal is easy: I want to extract from a 2D image, the pixel coordinates clicking with the mouse on it but then, I want to use these coordinates for different calculations.

I found different implementations using different libraries and the more interesting solution seems the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
def onclick(event):
    print('you pressed', event.key, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    X_coordinate = event.xdata
    Y_coordinate = event.ydata

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
lines, = plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

Now my problem is to get out the two variables (X_coordinate and Y_coordinate) and have them ad disposal for other uses.

I tried the following solution copied from here ([how to return a value from button_press_event matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032638/how-to-return-a-value-from-button-press-event-matplotlib)) to try to extract the X_coordinate but it does not work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
mutable_object = {} 
fig = plt.figure()
def onclick(event):
    print('you pressed', event.key, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    X_coordinate = event.xdata
    Y_coordinate = event.ydata
    mutable_object['click'] = X_coordinate

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
lines, = plt.plot([1,2,3])
X_coordinate = mutable_object['key']
plt.show()
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be the use of mutable_object['click'] in the function definition and mutable_object['key'] outside the function.  The key, 'key', is not in the dictionary mutable_object.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
mutable_object = {} 
fig = plt.figure()
def onclick(event):
    print('you pressed', event.key, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    X_coordinate = event.xdata
    Y_coordinate = event.ydata
    mutable_object['click'] = X_coordinate

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
lines, = plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
X_coordinate = mutable_object['click']
print(X_coordinate)
```

The example pasted below is from the matplotlib documentation and might be a better route in the long run.  The basic idea would be to create an object that stores the click locations in an attribute.  This attribute can then be called after your clicking is complete.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        print('click', event)
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line, = ax.plot([0], [0])  # empty line
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)

plt.show()
```